# Unavailable to use camera in Android

Tags: android, camera, barcode, barcode-scanner, zbar

It's my first question but I will try to explain the problem properly. I am tring to use ZBar (Barcode reader) in my android app. I don't want to use another barcode reader installed on the phone but implement ZBar into my code. I tried tips from [here](http://semycolon.blogspot.no/2014/12/first-android-app-step-8-zbar-barcode.html) on how this could be done.
The problem is I can't use hardware.Camera. I have attached a few print screens:

[image: AndroidManifest.xml]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android studio add in your gradle :

> compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zbar:1.8.4'

And read how to user: (Repo + Tutorial)

https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner#zbar